What is this connector called?
I'm trying to figure out what does this socket/connector/pin called EMR does on my motherboard(I couldn't find anything about it online). Obviously it's not soldered yet, but I'm soldering new connectors onto my mother board to do some upgrade(for example I soldered a new EMMC chip)


https://www.acronymfinder.com/Information-Technology/EMR.html

i don't think it's related at all

Yes, so do I. You need to provide more detail. It might even be that this is some special feature for another configuration of the MB; may depend on both software (driver) and additional components on the MB (which might not be present on your MB).

I belive this motherboard originally belong to a a lenovo chromebook yoga c630, model is "Pantheon" now it's running ubuntu and it did not show any driver related to this socket. it might has something to do with some peripheral device, because it's on the top of the motherboard near the integrated camera connector and the 40pin monitor socket

There is no connector installed at that position of the board. That footprint is for a 10-pin flat-ribbon cable connector. There's a similar fine-pitch flat-ribbon cable & connector to the lower-right of that footprint.
